# How do I tell what 3rd party module is importing rxjs?

Tags: angular, webpack, rxjs, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I'm working on optimizing my Angular 7 application, and in building it, I've found that I'm currently importing **all** rxjs operators even though I'm only specifying and using 5 of them.

I've checked and verified that my sytnax is correct, which has me believing that a third party library is currently improperly importing them.

Is there any way to use `webpack-bundle-analyzer` to see what is causing the full rxjs library to be bundled?

Comment: Sounds like you've got an issue tree shaking. I'd google "rxjs lettable operators" and if you want to see your dependency tree do `npm list` || `npm list rxjs`

Comment: What module are they being bundled into? Remember Angular itself relies heavily on rxjs, so it's expected to have a lot of rxjs imports into core.